# If a checkbox is checked how to set a dropdown as a required field on "if... AND..." condition in jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, if-statement

I need to solve this problem:

When a checkbox ("Session1") is ticked, then a "Select" list ("Course") should be filled from a dropdown list on condition that if "checkbox" is checked/"true" AND "select list" is empty, then the "select list" should be filled. And vice versa.

Right now I have this jquery code in my form:

```
$("#Session1").click(function () {
        {
    if($("#Session1").attr("checked")==true)
{
    alert("Course field is required");
}

}
    });
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You have a `{` and `}` which stand for nothing. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: Look into this: http://jsbeautifier.org/ - It will make code easier to debug.  You also have extra braces on the second and second to last lines.

Comment: Thanks! My fault :( I removed those extra braces. The code works as it's written, but I need to add this logic to it, such as "if($("#Session1").attr("checked")==true) && ($("txtCaterer"==null){
    alert("Course field is required");
}
 });
The second part of this logic is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#session1').change(function(){
   $('#session1_list').toggle('show');
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
    if($('#session1').is(':checked'))
    {
        if($('#session1_list').val().length < 1)
        {
            alert('Please select a course');
            return false;
        } 
    } 

    alert('form posted ok');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/n4xZU/

To force a required checkbox, simply check if it's required:

```
$('#session1').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':required') && !$(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        alert('Session1 is required!');
        $(this).prop('checked',true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/n4xZU/2/

Comment: Thanks! Your code makes sense. I need these alerts work when a checkbox ("Session 1") is checked AND a "Select Course" list is blank/empty. Or is a "Course" is selected AND the checkbox ("Session 1") is not checked/false. These alerts should pop-up before I hit a "Submit" button. I put this code, but I'm not sure where is my mistake in this condition:

Comment: $("#Session1").click(function ()
        {
    if($('#Session1').is(':checked') && ($('#Course').val().length < 1))
{
    alert("Course field is required");
}

    });
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Change `$("#Session1").click(function ()` to `$('#Session1, #Course').bind('change',function()`

Comment: @ AlienWebguy: I changed the code as you suggested to:
$('#Session1, #Course').bind('change',function()
       {
    if($("#Session1").is(":checked") && ($('#Course').val().length < 1))

{
    alert("Course is required");
}

    });
But now "alert" doesn't pop-up, and nothing happens at all. Do you have any idea, why? Thanks!

Comment: Just posted it at http://jsfiddle.net/Greg2325/gBzxs/
Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: `<select name="Course">` needs to be `<select id="Course" name="Course">` Same with the checkbox, it needs an `id="Session1"`

Comment: The example of your code at jsfiddle that you wrote earlier works great, I just cannot figure out how to get the same "alert" result without the "Submit" button event', but with just a "click" function in a checkbox or in the "select" list depending on "if...&&..." condition". Thank you million times!

Comment: I did it a few days ago, don't know if it was unchecked, sorry! Thanks again! 
The only thing I wanted to ask is about the forced required checkbox action. How does it work?

Answer (score -2):

Here is something you can use, you just need to do the leg work to make the dropdown list to populate based on whatever logic you want.

```
$("#Session1").click(function ()
{
   if($(this).is(":checked"))
   {
      alert("Course field is required");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The code in its current view works, but my problem is that the alert should pop-up only if the checkbox is checked AND the select list is empty. Could you please suggest how to make it working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I agree with @!Alien. Why would you alert "this is required" when they are checking the box?

Comment: Just a comment: alert("Course field is required") belongs to a "course" field which is a "select" field. They check another box, then the "course" field is 'required" if it's not been selected, 'empty'.

Comment: @CraigW: I'm using the code that you provided, it works and it's what i need. Just a part of the logic is missing, as if one field is checked/selected AND another is not, then an alert pop-ups. Otherwise these fields are optional. Can you please advise how to make these fields work together? 
I'd like to remove a "(-1)" from your post, do I need to register to do it? Thank you!